# How to execute background job that update UI view Android

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, background

In my Android application I have an activity with views.

To the beginning of the activity or to the creation of main layout for example, I would like to start a background job that goes to update UI view from main layout for each 5 seconds.

So, my strategy for the moment was to create Runnable during creation of the main layout by using runOnUiThread method of my class that derives from View.

The thread starts correctly but in the thread I would like to do a wait for 5 seconds to wait before update UI view again. My problem is when I use Thread.sleep, the UI is blocked.

I guess Thread.sleep() blocks the entire UI but I don't know how I must make to solve that problem.

So my question is the following : what is the best solution to realize what I want (without using sleep perhaps) ?

Comment: The following link has the answer for all your doubts: [Android Painless Threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2009/05/painless-threading.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) to schedule a repeating `TimerTask`. Each time you wanted to update the UI, you can post to a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) that you previously created in the UI thread.

Just remember to `cancel` your `Timer` in `onPause` and create a new `Timer` in `onResume`.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) with a Timer. You don't have to worry about handlers this way

Comment: I wasn't sure how to use a repeating task with `AsyncTask`. How would you do this?

Comment: You could have a while loop in the doInBackground that uses SystemClock.sleep(millis) to wait 5 min at the end of the loop. You could always just cancel(boolean) the AsynTask when you want to stop updating the task

Comment: When you want to stop updating the Activity i meant

Comment: Hmm, doInBackground doesn't run on the UI thread though. How would you have your code run on the UI thread?

Comment: Look at the link i put up (Click on AsyncTask). You call the method publishprogress(param) inside the loop  and  onProgressUpdate(param) will be called.  onProgressUpdate(param) runs on the UI thread

Comment: Yes, that seems like it would work. I'm also a fan of `AsyncTask`.