# How to update a TextView in an activity constantly in an infinite loop?

Tags: android, loops, infinite

I have an activity which has a TextView, and I want to update the text constantly..

In Java I could just make an infinite while loop, and just set the text each iteration.

But when I try to do that in Android, it shows a black screen, and doesn't even load the activity.

I put the infinite in the `onCreate` method, perhaps that's why it crashes..but if it is, where should I put it?

Comment: You shouldn't have an infinite loop, at least not on the main thread. What's the purpose of it? :-)

Comment: Well, I want something to update infinitely ( or at least constantly)

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295152/android-running-infinite-loop || http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099640/main-loop-in-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123231/android-count-down-timer-in-background || http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464990/how-to-execute-background-job-that-update-ui-view-android

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and a separate thread/runnable for updating TextView constantly instead of While loop :

```
Handler handler=new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable(){ 
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // upadte textView here
        handler.postDelayed(this,500); // set time here to refresh textView
    }
});
```

Comment: If you are going to refer to handler as part of that closure, you need to delcare it final.

Answer (score 4):

**Minimal working example**

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/14295193/895245:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final int i = 0;
        final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(String.format("%d", i));
        setContentView(textView);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
            private Handler handler;
            private int i;
            private TextView textView;
            public MyRunnable(Handler handler, int i, TextView textView) {
                this.handler = handler;
                this.i = i;
                this.textView = textView;
            }
            @Override
            public void run() {
                this.handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
                this.i++;
                this.textView.setText(String.format("%d", i));
            }
        }
        handler.post(new MyRunnable(handler, i, textView));
    }
}
```

You can just copy paste this into the main activity generated by `android create project [...]`, and you will see a counter on your app.

Tested on Android 22.